# Connecting to Host with ssh is always asking for a password

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh, debian

I am out of suggestions to successfully connect via SSH to our live server. It is always asking for a password, even though my keys are being allowed, according to the administrator.

This is the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
Host [server-host]
HostName [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
User root
IdentityFile /home/gabriel/.ssh/[server-host]_rsa.pub
```

Regardless of how I attempt to connect:

> ssh [server-name]
>
> ssh [server-ip]
>
> ssh root@[server-ip] (this usually used to work)

These will always prompt me a password input.

I've already changed the `.ssh` permissions to `700` and the files to `600` but it's hopeless, I don't know what else to do. I'm running Debian 8.8 in my machine, and the server is Ubuntu 14.04. I've also created a `.ssh/config` file, without success.

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, `PubkeyAuthentication` is **yes** and `AuthorizedKeysFile` is commented out. What else can I try?

Output with `-v`:

```
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/gabriel/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gabriel/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gabriel/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gabriel/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gabriel/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gabriel/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gabriel/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gabriel/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA aa:14:7a:eb:5d:34:82:b8:4f:44:18:f1:db:63:1c:d1
debug1: Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/gabriel/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/gabriel/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/gabriel/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/gabriel/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/gabriel/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
```

Comment: Make an ssh attempt with `-vvv` added to the command line arguments and add the output to your question.

Comment: I put with `-v`, the `-vvv` seemed to have too much info. It is trying to look for `id_rsa` apparently, even though I set another file.

Comment: The remote sshd has an id_rsa.pub, you need the corresponding id_rsa in your local `~/.ssh`, which doesn't seem to be there. Check the remote `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and your local '~/.ssh' for matching keys.

Answer (score 0):

The key was rejected by the server. Check the server configuraiton, errors and make sure the public key is correctly installed in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.